# Regex - To Select Everything But

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches everything that does not contain the string 'screen' but am having trouble doing so. I am able to select anything contains 'string', but I cannot seem to get the compliment by using `^`.

What my regex currently is: 
`.*/[0-9]+_screen.*`

*What I do not want to match:*

> /assets/1009947_screen930x524engb098+960sds6xdqe8s465sfa4sa6df4
>   /assets/1002583_screenhi930x524enus01201306121435130ab5f643a52998635b6d5
>   /assets/73051_screenhi_930x524_en_US_01_^_2013-08-22-11-38-58_4567c088cc7b886b428ebb2477603a119668f496

*What I am trying to match:*

> /assets/73052_exclsingle_290x215_en_CA_preorder_^_2013-08-13-13-33-45_b9970fd9321ffd93a3cb25bce01c49375b9fd820
>   /assets/73052_sb_63x89_enus2013052822092639b1cc7d33634ed3b99d5490c2429a3
>   /assets/73052_exclsingle_290x215_en_CA_preorder_^_2013-08-13-13-33-45_b9970fd9321ffd93a3cb25bce01c49375b9fd820
>   /assets/73052_sb_63x89_enus201304051542148d984af7dade033ede71b09bcc3a257/63.0x89.0.png

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
.*/[0-9]+_(?!screen).*
```

Here `(?!screen).*` will select anything but `screen`

Comment: It is possible to do this without a negative look ahead?

Comment: Possible but kludgy, any problem with lookahead?

Comment: My regex is going through my CMS which doesn't seem to support look ahead. I'm looking into look ahead alternatives as your code works in my Regex Tester

Comment: You can try this clumsy regex: `.*/[0-9]+_[^s][^c][^r][^e][^e][^n].*`

Comment: That one didn't work. It is not picking up the 2nd and 4th row of data that I am trying to pick up. I am unsure why that happened.

Comment: @anubhava that regex will fail to match any string that has an `s` following the `_`, and also will fail to match if the second character after the underscore is `c`, if the third is `r`, etc.

Comment: Yes that is true and I believe it will be a very long clumsy regex to replace a simple negative lookahead.

Comment: @anubhava Is there a regex that doesn't involve a negative look ahead that will also not fail the match if the second char after the underscore is a `c`, and third is a `r`...?

Comment: I tried to build one but without lookahead it is not behaving same.